# SQLite byte[] to varchar

Tags: sqlite, arrays, varchar

I have a column with byte[] values on a sqlite table, when I select all values from this column I get "System.Byte[]" on every row, when I try to use

```
cast(my_column as varchar(200))
```

I get weird characters

[image]

How can I convert a Byte[] to a readable string in sqlite?

Comment: What are the contents of this column? What format does it use?

Comment: The contents are of type Blob, Im using Database.net to explore my SQLite database and when I use "select * from my_table" I get "System.Byte[]" on every row

Comment: And what is stored in those blobs? In which format?